# How can I config NVim options to tab within functions, and do tab conversion automatically?

Tags: config, neovim

I'm setting a new NVim config file with an specific desired behavior:

1. Automatically indent with `<Tab>` at every newline `<\n>` within a function.
2. `<Tab>`s get converted into 4 whitespaces when added on newlines; (for consistency and clarity while writing code).

But so far I haven't been successful.
I have been reading the documentation on `softtabstop`, `autoindent`, `tabstop` and `smartindent`; but as much as I read them or edit the lua file I don't achieve the right configuration.

Thank you for your attention.

My current config:

```bash
vim.opt.tabstop=4
vim.opt.softtabstop=4
vim.opt.autoindent=true
vim.opt.smartindent=true
```

Nevertheless the results I'm getting with this configuration are not of clear behavior to me.

Answer (score 0):

Set [`expandtab` option](https://neovim.io/doc/user/options.html#%27expandtab%27) :

In Insert mode: Use the appropriate number of spaces to insert a Tab.  Spaces are used in indents with the '>' and '<' commands and when `autoindent` is on.

```
vim.opt.expandtab=true
```